# How can I remove the arrow from a single loop in a TikZ diagram, without using the 'every loop' command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to draw an example of a directed and undirected graph, and I would like to have the loop in the undirected graph with no arrow on it.

I know that i can use `\tikzset{every loop/.style={}}`, but I am more likely to do loops with arrows than without, and having to change all of my other diagrams so that they have `->` in the parameters for the loops would be a pain, and would probably cause a lot of dependency issues with other documents as well.

Here is the code for what i am trying to do:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.0cm,semithick,auto]
\foreach \i/\t in {0/directed,6/undirected}{
    \foreach \x/\y/\v in {0/2/a,2/2/b,0/0/c,2/0/d}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xx{\x+\i};
        \node [draw,circle,minimum size=4mm] (\i-\v) at (\xx,\y) {}; 
        \node at (\i-\v) {\(\v\)}; 
    }
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xt{\i+1};
    \node at (\xt,-0.6) {\t};
}

\path (0-b) edge[loop right] (0-b); 

\path (6-b) edge[loop right] (6-b); % this is the loop i want to change

\foreach \src/\tgt in {a/c,d/b,d/a}{
    \path (0-\src) edge (0-\tgt);
    \path [shorten >= 0pt,-](6-\src) edge (6-\tgt);
}

\path (0-c) edge[bend left=10] (0-d);
\path (0-d) edge[bend left=10] (0-c);
\path [shorten >= 0pt,-](6-c) edge (6-d);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And this is the output with the loop I want to change circled:

[image]

Is there a way that I can either create a macro that will insert a loop without an arrow, or add a parameter to the `edge[loop right]` to tell it not to draw an arrow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `every loop` key *locally*, i.e. in the path, so its global value won't change. That is, for all other paths you will still get the arrow.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,
    auto,node distance=2.0cm,semithick,auto]
\foreach \i/\t in {0/directed,6/undirected}{
    \foreach \x/\y/\v in {0/2/a,2/2/b,0/0/c,2/0/d}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xx{\x+\i};
        \node [draw,circle,minimum size=4mm] (\i-\v) at (\xx,\y) {}; 
        \node at (\i-\v) {\(\v\)}; 
    }
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xt{\i+1};
    \node at (\xt,-0.6) {\t};
}

\path (0-b) edge[loop right] (0-b); 

\path[every loop/.style={-}] (6-b) edge[loop right] (6-b); % this is the loop i want to change

\foreach \src/\tgt in {a/c,d/b,d/a}{
    \path (0-\src) edge (0-\tgt);
    \path [shorten >= 0pt,-](6-\src) edge (6-\tgt);
}

\path (0-c) edge[bend left=10] (0-d);
\path (0-d) edge[bend left=10] (0-c);
\path [shorten >= 0pt,-](6-c) edge (6-d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is really that in `tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex` there is

```
\tikzset{loop/.style=                    {to path={
  \pgfextra{\let\tikztotarget=\tikztostart}
  [looseness=8,min distance=5mm,every loop]
  \tikz@to@curve@path
  }}}

\tikzset{every loop/.style=              {->,shorten >=1pt}}
```

so a `loop` will always look at `every loop`.